# Start Task Process - Approve but not completing

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow-tasks-list

I am starting a task process (2013) and the task goes to 2 recipients, parallel. I only care if one of them approves. I checked off wait for task completion with criteria wait for first response.

My problem is that I want after the 1st person who approves i want the task to end and continue on in the workflow. As of now it's waiting for the person to actually click the checkbox and mark as completed. I just want it to continue on Approve.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose "wait for first response", when there is one person approve, the task will be completed, if you don't want to make the workflow completed, you can add another action in your workflow. such as"Wait for Field Change in Current Item".
[image]